# Testing my controller with Spock

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I need to test a controller, of action `index`(generated by the grails `generate-all` command). I have a test like this (in Spock) :

```
package mnm.schedule

import grails.test.mixin.*
import org.junit.*
import grails.plugin.spock.*
import spock.lang.Specification
import org.example.*;

class UserControllerSpec extends ControllerSpec {


def "test"() {
            setup:
            mockLogging(UserController, true)

            when:
            controller.index()

            then:
            redirectArgs.action == "list"
    }

}
```

I get a error like this :

```
Error Error running script test-app :spock : cannot find shared instance field (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

After sometime I can run the test, the Test is getting PASSED.

Whats actually going wrong? Why the first time it shows that error? I'm new to Spock environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take the advice of the error and run your test with the --stacktrace option.  That will give you way more info that our crystal balls will.

Comment: Which version of Grails are you targeting? If 2.x.x, try using the @TestFor(UserController) class-level annotation

Comment: @Esteban : Yes your correct. It worked. Why can't you put that as an answer?

Comment: There you go! I wasn't sure about which version you were using so I avoided posting a useless answer. Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you are using Grails 2.x.x, you should use the @TestFor annotation which enhances unit testing framework classes with mixins.

In your case, you should add `@TestFor(UserController)` as a class-level annotation, so you can use the `mockLogging` method.